# Automapper not mapping ID property of compose object when object is null

Tags: automapper, automapper-6

I am using [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) 6.2.2.0, which I think is the latest, in my web project ([ASP.NET WebForms](https://www.asp.net/web-forms)) and also in my **Business** layer, here is what [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) is not mapping and don't know why:

[image]

Here is the relationship in the database, also exist the corresponding **Business** Objects and the **Model** of the Database (using ***LINQ to SQL***)

[image]

this is the [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) profile:

```
public class ServicePlanProfile: Profile
{
    public ServicePlanProfile()
    {
        //ProcedureCodeUnits
        CreateMap<ExtendedProcedureCodeUnit, ProcedureCodeUnit>().ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<ExtendedProcedureCode, ProcedureCode>().ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<ExtendedServiceCategory, ServiceCategory>().ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<ExtendedServiceSubCategory, ServiceSubCategory>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

have this code in the ***Global.asax*** file to kick off the [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) configurations:

```
//Automapper configuration
    Mapper.Initialize(
        cfg=>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperProfile>();
            cfg.AddProfile<ServicePlanProfile>();
            cfg.AddProfile<IncidentTrackingProfile>();
        }
    );
```

And here, following the steps in the [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) docs, is the expression tree generated 
[image]

Don't know why [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) is not mapping ***ServiceCategoryID*** and ***ServiceSubCategoryID*** fields, any clue?

Comment: I did not it was possible to access the generated expression in automapper

Comment: In order to get the right execution plan you have to use the configuration you use for mapping. That's Mapper.Configuration in your case.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu how is it possible to get the generated expression trees

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I use Mapper.Configuration as you suggested but still the same. I did this:
 `CreateMap<ExtendedProcedureCode, ProcedureCode>()
                .ForMember(dest=>dest.ServiceCategory, opt=>opt.Ignore())
                .ForMember(dest=>dest.ServiceSubCategory, opt=>opt.Ignore())
                .ReverseMap();`
and now is mapping the correct values. Any idea why?

Comment: Probably [this](http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html).